# What's the pattern to share database to other module in security perspective?

Tags: architecture, database, security, abstraction, modules

In a large iOS application, I have a database module which is dedicated to handle application databases with read/write public APIs for other module. UI module has a feature to share the database, in which a copy of the database can be sent to another person. Now to attach my database for share feature UI module requires my database path. So, UI team requested to expose a public API to get the database path.

I am concern about security perspective of exposing database path as a public API. What are the general guideline to share the database for other modules? Should I expose my database path via public API? If so, is there any implication on further security vulnerability and does it violate the abstraction?

Comment: How "public" would this API be? Can anyone in the world access it with a HTTP call? Can I write an iOS application of myself that can access the API or is it only accessible from within *your* iOS application? Can I write a plugin for your application that can access the API? Or is it only the developers within your company who work on this application that can write the code that accesses the API?

Comment: As I said its a large application and each module has different dedicated team. Of course, all teams are within my single organisation. Some 3rd party applications also have limited access through deep links. I have asked the question for my large app with many modules and teams where even while developing a single small app, we are encouraged to design with proper abstraction and encapsulation because mistakes happen. @BartVanIngenSchenau

Comment: I did not mean to invalidate your question, but rather to get a feeling for the security impact that this API would have. Another question, what does it mean to "share the database"? What is the user supposed to get when they use that feature? Will the database path be shared with the user, or does the UI module want it to access the database themselves?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau The database will be zipped and attached with 3rd party share app like emai etc., No direct end user use case but  shared to internal developers for mostly debugging purpose.

Answer (score 2):

From a security perspective, the risks involved with exposing a database path/connection string to other modules in the same application, where those modules are developed by the same organisation, are low. It would take at least a bug in another component to expose the database path outside the application, but all those components can be vetted for improper use of this API.
Additionally, given the feature that asks for it, the database contents are probably not all that sensitive anyway.

From a design perspective, there are only a few reasons to expose the database path outside the component that deals with the database:

- configuration: It might be that the database path is read from a configuration file which is handled by a configuration module
- To show/edit by the user: There might be a feature whereby the user can see and/or change the database path. This could be coupled with the configuration mentioned before.

This database sharing feature appears to fit none of those reasons, so there should not be a reason to expose the database path for it. But, the iOS API use to do the actual sharing may need to receive the name of a file that gets shared. In that case, there are only two ways to implement the feature: you either pass that API the path to your actual database file, or the application copies the database contents into a new file.

To keep the separation of responsibilities between the components clear, I would go for a design like this:

- the database module offers an API to get the name of a file with the database contents in a format suitable for sharing
- the UI module can use that API to implement their part of the sharing feature
- the database module implements the API by either providing the actual database path, or by copying the database content to a file. Which of these options gets used is completely up to the team maintaining the database module and can be revised by them at any time.

Comment: I agree.  While it might be safe, there shouldn't be any good reason to expose inner working details like this.

Comment: I was thinking to invert of controlling the path. If callers pass the `path_to_copy` variable as param to the single database API, then no other database APIs to get the intermediate file path is required anymore. Moreover, callers will have the flexibility to get the database copied wherever they want. Whats your suggestion on it? @RobertHarvey and Bart?

Comment: Sure, but why should outside actors have to know anything about the paths inside your server?  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we are talking about a inter module communications within single large app and I have no server in this boundary yet. Other modules need to know the path to export the private database. Without database path how will this db be exported? Any other options?

Comment: Are these inter-module communications exposed to the public internet?

Comment: Please read the comments to the original post. This question has already been asked and clarified. @RobertHarvey

Comment: Got it.  So no, I don't think you should expose those kinds of internal details to the public Internet, unless you can secure the communications via encryption (TLS, etc.)

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, what will happen if `path_to_copy` refers to a location that is too small to store a copy of the database? If you really don't want the database component to manage the storage location of the copy, why not offer an API that returns a stream of the serialized database? Then the caller can decide if they want to store it in a file or keep it in memory.

Comment: @Bart that would be even a better idea, but in my case share API requires a path of the file. I think we can throw exceptions if such storage shortage occurs. Whats your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

I think we have an XY problem here.

Your UI team has a problem: They want to export a copy of the database (and presumably import it somewhere else). That's problem X. They thought about how to do this, and decided that they can solve their problem X by getting the path to the database, which is problem Y.

You know, and I know, that this is totally inappropriate. The path to the database is none of their business. It's an implementation detail that could change at any point. Your database implementation could change at any point so whatever they try is doomed to failure. Your database could contain private information that must never be exported.

Go back to them and ask them what is the *actual* problem they need to solve. And then you can help them solving that problem. If you make any changes to the database, it will be your responsibility to make sure that exporting code doesn't stop working. For exposing that path, refuse.

PS. You refuse for the simple reason that they want you to create a strong coupling between UI and database, which is an awful anti-pattern that should be avoided whenever possible. It's the kind of coupling that will cause you trouble for years to come.

To discuss with them: What is the problem that they actually try to solve? It's not just "we want to share the database". You can't just "share", you need to do something with it after sharing. My app has a database, 99% of which must never be shared, and 1% that doesn't make any sense to share because it is bound to the device where it's used. So "**we want to share the database**" means **they haven't thought their problem through**. And you can't propose an alternative *until they figure out what their actual problem is and tell you*.

Comment: Agreed its an XY problem, but if database team just deny to expose the API without justification and proposing an alternative candidate, it won’t be acceptable. However, UI teams problem is clear. They simply need to share the raw database wherever we changes in db doesn’t matter. How to solve this weird problem in better way?